# Using virtual methods in class derived from templated base class

Tags: c++, templates

Let's consider following example:

```
template<std::size_t F>;
class GenericColor
{
public:
    std::array<int, F> colorComponents;
    virtual void invertColor();
}

class RGBColor : public GenericColor<3>
{
    void invertColor();
}

class CMYKColor : public GenericColor<4>
{
    void invertColor();
}
```

How would I use virtual methods when my base class is templated? Is it even possible?

```
GenericColor *color = new CMYKColor();
```

Code below doesn't work. I think that **RGBColor** and **CMYKColor** have different base class and it causes the problem. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Move invertColor() into a different class and have GenericColor<> inherit from that?

Comment: Yeah, I would say `GenericColor` should be a true interface and not a template.  You can have a separate class template `ColorComponents<N>` to use by inheritance or composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the two derived classes have different base classes (different specializations of the `GenericColor` template). Both happen to define a virtual function named `invertColor`, but the two are not related as far as the compiler is concerned.

One solution would be to move `invertColor()` into its own class and derive `GenericColor<>` from that. That way, both `RGBColor` and `CMYKColor` would "mean the same thing" when they say `invertColor`.

```
struct IGenericColor
{
   virtual ~IGenericColor() = 0 {}
   virtual void invertColor() = 0;
};

template<std::size_t F>
class GenericColor : public IGenericColor
{
public:
    std::array<int, F> colorComponents;
    virtual void invertColor(); // maybe you don't need an override here?
};

// rest as before
```

aschepler's comment about separating out `ColorComponents` instead and using multiple inheritance/composition seems like a good idea too; probably a better one if it makes sense for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

`GenericColor` is not a class, not the way you have the hierarchy defined above.  You can *generate* `GenericColor<>` classes based on the class template, but each of them is a distinct class.

Virtual functions should work properly within the inheritance "silo" defined by each template specialization; in other words, `CMYKColor::invertColor()` should properly override `GenericColor<4>::invertColor()`.